# how can I get the selected columns fully and the sum column separately

Tags: sql

```
SELECT f_name,l_name,teachers.first_name,teachers.t_id,p_id,paid_amount,family_id,date,sum(payments.paid_amount)
FROM payments
LEFT JOIN family ON family.id = payments.family_id
LEFT JOIN teachers ON family.teacher_id = teachers.t_id
```

How can I get the selected columns fully and the sum column separately?
because that sum function makes all the selected result one row

```
SELECT f_name,l_name,teachers.first_name,teachers.t_id,p_id,paid_amount,family_id,date
FROM payments
LEFT JOIN family ON family.id = payments.family_id
LEFT JOIN teachers ON family.teacher_id = teachers.t_id
```

This query is working fine without the sum column

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: there are multible rows in my result, but when I add the sum column it makes the result one row

Comment: as in comment above update your question add a proper data sample and the expected result... please

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell the database, which column to use for aggregating the data. Don't know which database you are using, but some complain, that there is no `GROUP BY` statement in the SQL text.

Please try with the following query:

```
SELECT f_name,l_name,teachers.first_name,teachers.t_id,p_id,paid_amount,family_id,date,sum(payments.paid_amount)
FROM payments
LEFT JOIN family ON family.id = payments.family_id
LEFT JOIN teachers ON family.teacher_id = teachers.t_id
GROUP BY f_name,l_name,teachers.first_name,teachers.t_id,p_id,paid_amount,family_id,date
```

`GROUP BY` tells the database, which are the key columns in the aggregation.

Comment: that shows all the records but what i want is to show all pait_amount records sum in one row

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the payments, use a subquery or `join`:

```
SELECT f_name, l_name, t.first_name, t.t_id, p.p_id, p.paid_amount, p.family_id, date,
       (select sum(p.paid_amount) from payments) as all_paid
FROM payments p LEFT JOIN
     family f
     ON f.id = p.family_id LEFT JOIN
     teachers t
     ON f.teacher_id = tetchers.t_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT f_name,l_name,t.first_name,t.t_id,p_id,paid_amount,family_id,date,sum(p.paid_amount)
FROM payments p,family f,teachers t where f.id = p.family_id and f.teacher_id = t.t_id
Group by f_name,l_name,teachers.first_name,teachers.t_id,p_id,paid_amount,family_id
```

You can add date column also in `Group by` expression based on your requirement. Example:

```
f_name,l_name,teachers.first_name,teachers.t_id,p_id,paid_amount,family_id,date
```